# Looking for low-mid range desktop computer specs for a basic GIS user

Tags: hardware-recommendations

I am replacing a computer in our organization for someone who uses a desktop GIS software (ArcGIS Pro for the moment). It is really a basic usage (maybe occasional small geoprocessing...) and I am trying to make it kind of future proof (6-7 years).

You should know that all of our data is stored on a server and served through a gigabit network link. So maybe a SSD cache would be more profitable in the server rather than in the client's machine?

I am hesitating for:

- i3 6th VS. i5 6th
- SSD cache VS SSD (os) and HDD (data) VS. HDD only
- Dedicated GPU VS. Integrated CPU chip

What would be the best compromise here?

Comment: If you want this computer to last 6-7 years, you need to over-spec it if using the current minimum Pro requirements. Based on history, Pro will take more space with each new release, employee may start doing more advanced work, etc.

Comment: 6-7 years is nearly three computer generations. It is not possible to make a  "future proof" purchase with that long a lead time. It will be barely adequate in three years and decrepit in six.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the specs that are specified on the ArcGIS Pro 2.0 website found [here](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/get-started/arcgis-pro-system-requirements.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_441BC14AD47145C1BF1ED8289CC238F2). As for the hard drive, I'd always recommend going for the SSD as the performance is unmatched.

CPU speed
Minimum: Hyperthreaded dual core*
Recommended: Quad core*
Optimal: 2x hyperthreaded hexa-core*

Platform
x64 with SSE2 extensions

Memory/RAM
Minimum: 4 GB
Recommended: 8 GB
Optimal: 16+ GB

Display properties
24-bit color depth

Also see ArcGIS Pro system requirements below.

Screen resolution
1024x768 or higher at normal size (96 dpi)

Visualization cache
The temporary visualization cache for ArcGIS Pro can consume up to 32 GB of space, if available, in the user-selected location. By default, the visualization cache is written to the user profile.**

Storage
Minimum: 4 GB of free space
Recommended: 6 GB or more of free space on a solid-state drive (SSD)